# how to change schema type for single document value

Tags: python, flask, eve

I want to change the default type from dict to string for a particular user.

```
DOMAIN = {
       'item': {
           'schema': {
               'profile':{
                   'type': 'dict'
                   },
               'username': {
                   'type': 'string'
                   }
               }
       }
   }
```

suppose if I get a request from x user type should not change. If I get a request from y user type should change from dict to string. How to change for a particular item resource without affecting others.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best approach would probably be to set up two different API endpoints, one for users of type X, and another for users of type Y. Both endpoints would consume the same underlying datasource (same DB collection being updated). You achieve that by setting the `datasource` for your endpoint, like so:

```
itemx = {
    'url': 'endpoint_1',
    'datasource': {
        'source': 'people',           # actual DB collection consumed by the endpoint
        'filter': {'usertype': 'x'}   # optional
        'projection': {'username': 1} # optional
    },
    'schema': {...}                   # here you set username to dict, or string
}
```

Rinse and repeat for the second endpoint. See the [docs](http://python-eve.org/config.html#multiple-api-endpoints-one-datasource) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, is there any chance for overriding data schema validations for a specific resource?